# Changing list content without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to accomplish a simple bootstrap list-group to change content on the page without reloading the page.

** I am coding with ruby on Rails and javascript/jquery

my html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <div id="jumbomambo"class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Linux Administration</h1><br />
        <p>Teachers Name <%= link_to "Send Message", "#", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="list-content">
          <div id="install" class="list-pane">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
            <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="exercises" class="list-pane hidden">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="homework" class="list-pane hidden">
            <h3>Section C</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="projects" class="list-pane hidden">
            <h3>Section D</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group" id="myList">
        <a href="#install" class="list-group-item active">Installation</a>
        <a href="#exercises" class="list-group-item">Excercises</a>
        <a href="#homework" class="list-group-item">HomeWork</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="list-group-item">Projects</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what should look my javascript to manage the purpose?
I tried hiding, on click event and collapsing.
Probably there is even better way.

I am using ruby to work with javascript

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
<% end %>
```

Then adding the code to manage active list(which also doesnt work ;(   )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-group-item").live('click', function(){ 
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    console.log($(this).html()); 
  });
});
```

Please help me correcting this one and coding the content show/hide.

Thanks alot!!

Comment: I can help with the jQuery function that you mentioned, but I am a bit unsure of the functionality that you would like to achieve. Do you mean that when the page loads, only section A / ID=install should be visible, and when a link is clicked it should have the `active` class applied to it and the corresponding `list-pane` have the hidden class removed and become the only one visible?

Comment: @runningviolent You are correct. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hellow kiper
    For this kind of functionality better to use ajax. check this tutorial for example https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails